# Highchart aggregate JSON data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Trying to use highcharts in react and my data is in the below format:

```
data: [{
        country: 'USA',
        color: '#00FF00',
        population: 10
    }, 
    {
        country: 'USA',
        color: '#00FF00',
        population: 2
    },
    {
        country: 'Canada',
        color: '#00FF00',
        population: 13
    }]
```

What I want to achieve: A column chart with one bar for each unique country(in this example, two bars USA & Canda) and each bar should show the sum of population. That is, USA with 12 and Canada with 13. Also the `xAxis` names should be `USA` and `Canada`.

Is there any option to group by/sum which highchart offers out of the box to solve my case?

When I google 'highchart data aggregation' the first result takes me to the [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping) but it doesn't help.
Related jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/smj8qwun/1/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to reduce the data to the format you're looking for, like so:

```js
let o = {
  data: [{
      country: "USA",
      color: "#00FF00",
      population: 10,
    },
    {
      country: "USA",
      color: "#00FF00",
      population: 2,
    },
    {
      country: "Canada",
      color: "#00FF00",
      population: 13,
    },
  ]
}

let formattedData = o.data.reduce((p, c) => {
  let found = p.find((o) => o.country === c.country);
  if (found) {
    found.y += c.population;
  } else {
    let {
      population,
      ...rest
    } = c;
    p.push({ ...rest,
      y: population
    });
  }
  return p;
}, []);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: formattedData.map(o => o.country)
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      // general options for all series
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    },
  },

  series: [{
    data: formattedData
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert only `country` to `name`, `population` to `y` and enable stacking:

```
series: [{
  type: 'column',
  stacking: true,
  data: [{
      name: 'USA',
      color: '#00FF00',
      y: 10
    },
    {
      name: 'USA',
      color: '#00FF00',
      y: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'Canada',
      color: '#00FF00',
      y: 13
    }
  ]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4980/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stacking